# How to initialize a reference to an empty STL container in a constructor?

Tags: c++, stl, reference

The question pretty much says it all. I need to initialize a reference to an empty STL container (more precisely, `std::set`).

Attempting to:

```
typedef std::set<bozo *> bozo_set;
class BozoClass { public: BozoClass(): bozosetref(bozo_set()) {} }
```

will obtain compiler errors similar to:

```
bozo.cc:104: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘bozo_set&’ from a temporary of type ‘bozo_set’
```

(Just a side note: this is **not** asking whether I should or not use `typedef` for this or not. I take comments about it, but this isn't really the actual question.)

EDIT: Since there've been a lot of comments about this, the point of having a reference to this is to allow outer classes to change `bozo` elements of this set, instead of having a ton of unneeded methods in `BozoClass` to manage the set.

Comment: What would you use it for? It's a dangling reference right after anyway. The fact that the set contains pointers (especially raw ones) sets off an alarm as well.

Comment: `bozosetref` is a reference type (`std::set<bozo*>&`) which can't bind to a temporary.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You're asking how to take a reference to a temporary, when you should be asking how to construct a class which owns a set and provides easy access to that set to clients of the owning class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is actually well-described by the compiler error:

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘bozo_set&’ from
>   a temporary of type ‘bozo_set’

The compiler is telling you that you are trying to take the reference of a temporary.  You can't* do this because the thing you are taking a reference to is *temporary*.  In other words, it will cease to exist immediately.  The temporary being referred to is the `bozo_set` you are constructing here:

```
bozosetref(bozo_set())
           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

As soon at the expression `bozosetref(bozo_set())` has finished executing, the `set` instantiated in `bozo_set()` will be destroyed.

Presumably, `bozosetref` is a member variable of type `set<bozo*>&`.

It seems to me like `BozoClass` is intended to *own* the `set` that you are trying to take a reference to.  That is fine, but the way you normally do that is by not taking a reference to the `set`, but by simply instantiating one directly:

```
class BozoClass 
{ 
public: 
  BozoClass() {}
private:
  set<bozo*> mBozos;
};
```

Now, `mBozos` is not a reference to the `set`, but the `set` itself.

You can then provide a reference to it to clients of `BozoClass` through an accessor:

```
class BozoClass
{
public:
  // ...
  set<bozo*>& GetBozos() { return mBozos; }
};
```

Clients can in turn use & modify the `set` directly through this accessor:

```
int main()
{
  BozoClass bc;
  bc.GetBozos().insert (new bozo); // or something
}
```

---

- Actually, you can but *shouldn't* do this.  Since the set itself hasn't been assigned to a variable, there is nothing "holding" on to it.  The reference you took to it becomes invalid.

Comment: @Matoe: I already answered that -- "it will cease to exist immediately."

Comment: So, what'd be a decent way of allowing clients to change the set? Since only allowing the set to be directly accessible to accessors will generate a copy of the object, so changes won't apply.

Comment: @Matoe:  The accessor I defined above returns a *reference* to the set owned by `BozoClass`.  No copies are created.  The set owned by `BozoClass` is modified directly.

Comment: Yes, but isn't the accessor which you defined above what you defined as something I shouldn't do?

Comment: @Matoe:  No.  My accessor returns a reference to the set owned by `BozoClass`.  `mBozos` is not a temporary.  What I said you shouldn't do is return a reference to a temporary, which is what you were originally doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <set>

struct Class {
    Class() : set(), setref(set) {}

    std::set<void *> set;
    std::set<void *> &setref;
};
```

Comment: If your solution is having the set and the reference, why not just have the set. The reference becomes redundant.

Comment: I think there must be more to the question.  For example, if you have multiple constructors within the class, one of which gives you the container to hold the reference to, and another which does not (and you're expected then to allocate your own).  Otherwise, yeah, it's weird.

Comment: I've added an edit to my question about the reason for using a reference.

Comment: @Borgleader: I agree, I don't see why and how this might be useful. But it initializes reference in constructor, which is what was asked about :) Why not have a set? Well, IDK, maybe it could be moved to global scope... Who knows.

Comment: @Matoe: Your rationale doesn't make any sense. Reference doesn't help at all in that case, just have a damn set and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass references to non const objects.
In your case if such thing would be allowed you would get reference to the already deleted temporarily instance of bozo_set in your class, but not a reference to an empty set.